# Disable GUI when doing background operation

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one form where there is a Button Copy along with other Controls. When the user presses the Copy Button, a BackgroundWorker does the copy operation.

During the copy operation I am disabling the Controls and re-enabling them upon completion.  Is there anyway I can do it in an easier way.  Like Disable and Enable all keyboard/Mouse input.

PS: If the user clicks while its showing the Hour-Glass icon, it should not collect all those clicks and fire them when the GUI is free.  When the GUI gets free it should remove all the clicks accumulated.

Answer (score 2):

Set the form `Enable` to be false in the start, handle the finish event of the background worker and re-enable the form.

```
//Lock the form
this.Enabled = false;
```

Should do it? Excuse me if this isn't what your looking for.

EDIT:

If your looking for a fancier way of doing this you could get an animated .GIF loader from somewhere like here - http://ajaxload.info/ and then create a `form` with a picture box, no borders with a transparent background. Then use the GIF in there and call `ShowDialog` at the start and close the dialog at the end of processing, this will display a loader similar to what you see being commonly used and lock the `parent` form.

Comment: this.Enabled = false; will grey-out the entire form which I dont want. I just want to show the hour-glass and disable all mouse/keyboard input.

Comment: @AkshayJ Sorry it wasn't clear that you didn't want to do that, what about my second comment with regards to a .GIF loading form would that work for you?

Comment: Is this web application so you can use ajax?

Comment: @CuongLe no the tag in the question says winforms, the ajaxload link is basically just to get suitable .GIF loading image nothing to do with AJAX as confusing as it may be.

Comment: you can see the tag winforms on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable all controls, you can create new form which will be active while background process is running. You can use this form to show progress, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The `Form` class also has the `Enabled` property.

By disabling the `Form` every control on the form will also be disabled. This is probably the easiest way to disable the entire window.

**Edit:**

If you *really* just want to just disable any input and not doing anything else, despite this being counter-intuitive and confusing for the user, then you could add a new control like a label with no content and a transparent background on top of the form.

Something like this:

```
// When starting the operation:
var transparentLabel = new Label();
transparentLabel.Bounds = form.Bounds;
// You may have to set the bacground and border and stuff, I am unsure
form.Children.Add(transparentLabel);
// Change cursor to a hourglass as well?


// When the operation is done
form.Children.Remove(transparentLabel);
// Change cursor back
```

This should ensure that the transparent label gets focus and disables input to the other controls.

Comment: this.Enabled = false; will grey-out the entire form which I dont want. I just want to show the hour-glass and disable all mouse/keyboard input.

Comment: Yes it will "grey-out" the entire form. But that is what the user of your application expects from a Windows application and hence it is what your application should do!

Comment: There is one software CCleaner, when its removing the junk, the same thing happens what I just require and its a very famous application. I am not sure how they did it and hence posted this question.